# Long delay between ClientBeginRequest and ClientDoneRequest in IE Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, performance-testing

My Web application loads slow in the IE browser. Tried to test using Fiddler - we found out there is long delay between ClientBeginRequest and ClientDoneRequest please refer below fiddler test output -

### **In IE Browser :-**

```
ClientConnected:    08:04:22.609
**ClientBeginRequest:   08:04:23.841**
GotRequestHeaders:  08:04:23.841
**ClientDoneRequest:    08:04:26.781**
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    08:04:22.618
FiddlerBeginRequest:    08:04:26.781
ServerGotRequest:   08:04:26.781
ServerBeginResponse:    08:04:26.904
GotResponseHeaders: 08:04:26.904
ServerDoneResponse: 08:04:26.904
ClientBeginResponse:    08:04:26.904
ClientDoneResponse: 08:04:26.904

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:03.063
```

The same is seen in IE F12 Console as **"Start Time"**

Why is there a long delay between ClientBeginRequest and ClientDoneRequest in IE browser and how to improve this ,  Overall Elapsed time is very high compare to chrome result (refer below).

**Google Chrome :-**

```
ClientConnected:    08:03:38.089
ClientBeginRequest: 08:03:39.186
GotRequestHeaders:  08:03:39.186
ClientDoneRequest:  08:03:39.186
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    08:03:38.097
FiddlerBeginRequest:    08:03:39.187
ServerGotRequest:   08:03:39.187
ServerBeginResponse:    08:03:39.186
GotResponseHeaders: 08:03:39.350
ServerDoneResponse: 08:03:39.350
ClientBeginResponse:    08:03:39.350
ClientDoneResponse: 08:03:39.350
```

Comment: Could be some sort of authentication issue...

Comment: Did you try to check any JS error?

Comment: Can you provide your web application URL ?